# Bash script: ensure process has terminated without waiting unnecessarily

Tags: linux, bash

The following Bash script calls shutdown on Tomcat, waits 120 seconds and then kills the process (if deemed necessary).

The issue is that the user must wait for 120 seconds regardless of whether the process has already terminated. In Bash, how can I modify the script to exit immediately if the process has terminated or kill it if a certain time period has elapsed?

```
sh $PROGRAMX_HOME/server/bin/shutdown.sh 2>/dev/null
sleep 120
PROCESS_ID=`ps -ef | grep programx | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' `
if [ "x$PROCESS_ID" != "x" ]
then
        kill -6 $PROCESS_ID 2>&1 >/dev/null
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same method that you use for detecting the process is still running should be usable to see if it's *not.*

Something like this should do it, keeping in mind the possibility that there *may* be potential problems with that way of detecting if the program is running in the first place <sup>(a)</sup>:

```
sh $PROGRAMX_HOME/server/bin/shutdown.sh 2>/dev/null

# Get initial PID and set limit.

PROCESS_ID=$(ps -ef | grep '[p]rogramx' | awk '{print $2}')
((LIMIT = 120))

# Loop every second, until process is gone or timer expires.

while [[ "x$PROCESS_ID" != "x" ]] ; do
    sleep 1
    PROCESS_ID=$(ps -ef | grep '[p]rogramx' | awk '{print $2}')
    ((LIMIT = LIMIT - 1))
    if [[ $LIMIT -eq 0 ]] ; then
        PROCESS_ID=""
    fi
done

PROCESS_ID=$(ps -ef | grep '[p]rogramx' | awk '{print $2}')
if [ "x$PROCESS_ID" != "x" ]
then
        kill -6 $PROCESS_ID >/dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

It's basically a loop which runs for *up to* 120 seconds (roughly) but stops prematurely if the process disappears, waiting at *most* a second or so after the process actually exits.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> A better way of detecting the process (without trying to parse the output of `ps`) would be to use `kill -0` which doeesn't actually *send* a signal to the process, it just returns a result stating whether the process exists.

Incorporating that `kill -0` method would give you code like:

```
# Get process ID up front.

PROCESS_ID=$(ps -ef | grep '[p]rogramx' | awk '{print $2}')

# Only act if it's running.

if kill -0 $PROCESS_ID >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    sh $PROGRAMX_HOME/server/bin/shutdown.sh 2>/dev/null
    ((LIMIT = 120))

    # Loop every second, until process is gone or timer expires.

    while kill -0 $PROCESS_ID >/dev/null 2>&1 && [[ $LIMIT -gt 0 ]] ; do
        sleep 1
        ((LIMIT = LIMIT - 1))
    done

    # Be more forceful if it's still up.

    if kill -0 $PROCESS_ID >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
        kill -6 $PROCESS_ID >/dev/null 2>&1
    fi
fi
```

---

You'll also notice that I've changed your `2>&1 >/dev/null` into `>/dev/null 2>&1`. If you want to throw away *all* messages, that's important - the order on the command line has subtle effects.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try quick. Is this Posix compatible?

Comment: @jamie: assuming you mean the `kill -0`, yes. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html.

Comment: I tried the script. after the process exits normally, it still tries to kill the process even though it is not present. kill: (15279) - No such process

Comment: @jamie, that's the `kill -0`, it's not trying to actually kill the process. I'll update the script to fix that.

Comment: I was just looking for a way to wait till a process exits. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `kill -0` to check if the process is still alive.

This would continue immediately if the process has already stopped, or wait 2 minutes if it hasn't:

```
kill -0 $PROCESS_ID &>/dev/null && sleep 120
```

Comment: That will detect the case where the process has already exited but, if it takes five seconds to exit, you'll still be waiting around for the full two minutes. Still, the use of `kill -0` is a good idea.